# Why arrays of objects has ids on Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've went through some problems while saving some documents and realized that some inner documents has id references.

Let's take this schema for example:

```
var VisitSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    name: String,
    city: {
        name: String,
        reference: String,
        location: [Number]
    },
    photos: [{
        image_url: String,
        description: String
    }]
});
```

When this schema is saved, here is the resulting document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5449eceeea5281056768aef8"),
    "user_id" : ObjectId("540603dd797be100008b4340"),
    "name" : "Test",
    "photos" : [ 
        {
            "image_url" : "testURL",
            "description" : "testDescription",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5449eceeea5281056768aefb")
        }
    ],
    "city" : {
        "name" : "New York, NY, United States",
        "reference" : "CoQBdAAAAFfbZuaWptFtAkhGaO87UVSaXbyYwtTY_xX-pH84mS6QO2ypLr15znsCnYvaZ_N8CvwCBAr4y34PSQqyTUwxa5qbUKBK0yHnUFgTLKPQMFKqyQ8xd4vcDPNXf5XSxlpsXKKPYnU0AJZEVVxXLJ_6IBiUay9emFvNXPiYb7kT04NjEhB8fK-jKIZHJ5Bfz_mfyk2MGhTJwOPU68NQiV7RlAdb0Gca1bg0ew",
        "location" : [ 
            -74.0059413, 
            40.7127837
        ]
    },
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Why does the subdocument `photos` has an **id** reference? It doesn't make sense.

Thanks.

Comment: Please, provide example from your code, where you are save object of this schema

Comment: How to disable it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20863441/why-is-an-id-with-objectid-added-to-when-using-mongodbs-push-to-add-new-objec