# MongoDB _id field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having trouble understanding with MongoDB is doing with my documents. I have a collection of a certain document. This document has a schema (I'm using Node.js Mongoose server-side). It has a couple of arrays of sub-documents. When I save a document that does not have an _id field Mongo should generate an _id field which it does. However, some of my 'sub-documents' also seem to have been given an _id field and other types of custom sub-documents were not. What the heck is going on here? Shouldn't I just get one _id per document?

Comment: It's probably better if you show how you are making your sub-documents . are using `.push()`? It says to use `.push()`  at http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html

Comment: I'm sorry, I was using the term subdocuments without knowing that they are an actual thing in MongoDB. I simply meant I had documents within a document (no schema). I'm not sure I understand if I need to define an actual sub-document schema or not. I guess I'll have to research

Comment: I think what you might be doing is adding object to a field. for example: "users" :[{name :"name1"}, {name : "name2}, {name : "name3"}] those objects inside the users field  will not create an objectID. I believe that those are objects not documents in a collection. The document that `users` is in will get an objectID but the objects inside users will not. I believe you can create an objectId your self and place them in the objects to mimic documents

Comment: Could you paste a snippet of code highlighting what you've tried and what output you received? This will help others provide a solution.

Comment: The `_id` fields in the array elements are added by Mongoose, not by MongoDB itself. So you'll only see those if the element was added via Mongoose. You can disable them in your schema definition if you don't want them, see [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20863441/why-is-an-id-with-objectid-added-to-when-using-mongodbs-push-to-add-new-objec).

Comment: Sure, please see http://pastebin.com/dekByVD9 for an explanation and example. I trimmed out all fields except for _id for clarity.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to disable the unnecessary _ids I didn't need with that question.